# Environment.SpecialFolder problems

Tags: c#, methods, environment-variables

How would i enter a string to replace

(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) as the .ApplicationData part needs to change depending on variables passed to it.

```
string specialFolder = ("Environment.SpecialFolder." + specialLocation);
specialLocation = "this will change depending on path location"; 
path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath("specialFolder"),
                @""+backupPath);
```

hope i have made it clear enough.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is your answer

For example:

```
string s = "ApplicationData";
Environment.SpecialFolder sf;
if(Enum.TryParse<Environment.SpecialFolder>(s, true, out sf))
     Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetFolderPath(sf));
```

So, your code could be written as:

```
Environment.SpecialFolder sf;
if(Enum.TryParse<Environment.SpecialFolder>(specialLocation, true, out sf))
{
    path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(sf), backupPath);
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string value using enum. U can use Parse if you want the exception to be thrown in case the string isnt correct. A safer way is to use try parse.

```
Environment.SpecialFolder folder;
                if (Enum.TryParse<Environment.SpecialFolder>("ApplicationData",true, out folder))
                {
                    var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(folder);
                }
```